# Android studio, kotlin fails when trying to use immersive mode

Tags: android, kotlin, view, hide, screen

I'm trying to learn android studio, android, and kotlin. Mostly this has been straightforward but with a few glitches. One such glitch is the following for which I could use some help:

I'm trying to create a phone view in immersive mode. According to the documentation (https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive) the following function should do the trick.

```
private fun hideSystemBars() {
    val windowInsetsController =
        ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(window.decorView) ?: return
    // Configure the behavior of the hidden system bars
    windowInsetsController.systemBarsBehavior =
        WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
    // Hide both the status bar and the navigation bar
    windowInsetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
}// end hideSystemBars function
```

I set this in the main Activity onCreate function as follows

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

       binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        supportActionBar?.hide()

        setContentView(binding.root)
        hideSystemBars()

    }// end onCreate function
```

Unfortunately I seem to missing something basic as this always fails because
`ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(window.decorView)` always returns null (I ran several tests to verify this)

I've verified that window.decorView is not null and looks okay. As a precaution I replaced the `hideSystemBars()` function call with `window.decorView.doOnLayout {hideSystemBars()}` in case the layout wasn't complete but this doesn't help. In fact, from some addition tests I ran use of the `window.decorView.doOnLayout {}` doesn't seem to work either no matter what function is used in the brackets (another glitch I don't understand)

I think I may be missing something basic (and possibly trivial) but cannot seem to discover how to make this work. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check your API Level on the device. The following solution works for me.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            val windowInsetsController = ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(window.decorView) ?: return
            // Configure the behavior of the hidden system bars
            windowInsetsController.systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
            // Hide both the status bar and the navigation bar
            windowInsetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
        }else{
            val flags =
                (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY)
            window!!.decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(flags)
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer 
FYI: I'm using Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1 patch 1. The device API level is 27. 

At first your solution didn't work as Android Studio wouldn't let me form the flags value; but after I place
 @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
before my hideSystemBars() method it worked. Now I just have to figure out a way to insure that my fragments maintain this condition when I navigate fragment views.

Comment: You could call this function in every fragment you need it (onCreateView) if you use requireActivity().window... instead of window.... .